# What application server or web framwork to use

Tags: python, web-mapping, java, php

I'm looking to make a webmapping app, which gonna use Geoserver as carto server, and Postgres/postgis as Dabatase, and Extjs as client UI.

but i'm in dilemma in application server side, between PHP, PHP framework(Symfony), Python (geodjango), Java.

Any Ideas, Experiences, Recommandations.

Comment: What is your key requirement on the application server side?  What are your experiences with PHP, PHP framework(Symfony), Python (GeoDjango) and Java that make choosing one over the others not an obvious choice?  Answering these within your question should help focus it to something less broad.

Comment: I can work with php , python , and java , i've used symfony in a small project 5 years ago, i need to be capable to do geometric manipulations and very customizable reporting in application server

Answer (score 1):

I think the application server will be doing very little so I would just go with whatever web framework you are already familiar with.

You can configure GeoServer completely using their [REST API](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/) and you can manipulate/query the data directly from GeoServer using WMS/WFS (preferably with JSONP) without having to touch PostGIS directly.

All the application server will likely be doing is handling authentication. Also for the client side I would recommend Leaflet and JQuery above ExtJS.